# Ubuntu terminal proxy settings when using it in a vertual machine

Tags: ubuntu, proxy, terminal, vmware-workstation

I am using Ubuntu Mate in Vmware virtual machine that installed in windows 10 64bit.I can log in to the internet through fire fox and other servers in ubutu when run it in the vmware.But i cannot connect to the internet or install any libraries from the terminal in the ubutu.How can i fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you be more specified? As you describe that you can use firefox to browse, but is it inside your ubuntu VM or in your windows 10?

If the latter one, maybe you need to configure the network of your virtual machine as "NAT"(VMnet8 usually).[something about virtual network editor](https://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1018697)

Else maybe your need to configure your [apt source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/CommandLine)